# Electron creating app - suppress desktop icon & fill help menu

Tags: html, windows, electron, desktop

I am a first-time user with electron. I used it successfully to create a windows desktop app.
I just followed this great description: [text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u72CCP4Ae8s&t=964s).

Now I have two basic questions:

1. When I run the app I created an icon is automatically created on my desktop
   (C:\Users...\AppData\Local\MyTool\MyTool.exe). How can I suppress that?
   Something like *"createStartMenuShortcut": false* ? Where?
2. A menu is also automatically created, which is fine for me. But I wonder how I can customize the help?
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ksky.png)
   I want to enter there just basic information like:

"In case of further questions, please contact XXX@info.com."

Any help is appreciated :-) Thank you!

I figured out how to hide the menu bar completely....

mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 640, height: 360})
mainWindow.setMenuBarVisibility(false)

Comment: When you use [NSIS](https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis) or [MSI](https://www.electron.build/configuration/msi) you can use `createDesktopShortcut`, but [Squirrel.Windows](https://www.electron.build/configuration/squirrel-windows) doesn't seem to have it.